# .htaccess redirection to specific route

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a set of specific pages with particular parameters in the URL. I am a bit familiar with .htaccess redirections but this one is giving me a headache.

I want to redirect https://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php?page=shop.ask&flypage=flypage_images.tpl&product_id=182&category_id=39&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=9

TO:
 https://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php?page=shop.ask

This is the rule that I have written for redirecting index and index2 but the parameters after "?" are being taken as an OR

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule index[0-2]*.php?page=shop.(.*)$ https://www.xxxxx.com/index.php?page=shop.ask [R]
```

I need to escape the '?' as its taking the php as ph or php and the parameters after that are not being taken into consideration by the apache.

I have tried using the REWRITECOND as well using this rule but it doesn't work.

Please suggest the correct redirect rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `RewriteCond`. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=shop.ask&flypage=flypage_images.tpl&product_id=182&category_id=39&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=9
RewriteRule ^index.php https://www.xxxxx.com/index.php?page=shop.ask [R,L]
```

This should work as long as your query string always appears in the exact order you specified. Otherwise you'll need to create a bunch of `RewriteConds` for each parameter in combination with `[AND]`.